# Many-to-One collection not restored from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm following the official ["Getting Started" EF Core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli), which defines a many-to-one relationship (one blog has many posts). Everything looks good until I remove the deletion of the blog at the end of the program and restart it.

I expect the `Blog` object to be restored from the database with the same data as before. But what I find is that the blog is there with the correct ID and URL, but the `Blog.Posts` collection is empty. Even though the blog's post is present in the database.

This seems wrong...is it? Or am I supposed to populate the collection manually?

I'm working on Linux and the database is SQLite.

---

Here is Microsoft's data model, for reference:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>();
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You only showed some classes without any code. Please also show the code using those classes and producing the issue.

Comment: It's the official EF Core tutorial. All of the code is available from the link at the very start of the post.

Comment: We do not care about the code a the link, but about code you are *using*. Because that is the one causing problems.

Comment: Well, the tutorial lacks [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) example.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[An extra configuration step, not mentioned in the tutorial, is needed to restore entity collections.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) I enabled lazy-loading proxies and now the data is restored correctly.